# How to interpret JSON field with '-' in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am using the node.js to interpret a JSON data, the data format is like this below

```
{
  "href": "https://localhost/light/0000293D",
  "i-object-metadata": [
    {
      "rel": "temperature",
      "val": "244"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can print the raw data using `print (body)`
to interpret data all works except printing the field `i-object-metadata`

```
var obj = JSON.parse(body);
console.log(obj.items);   // works well
console.log(obj.i-object-metadata);   // error
```

How could I interpret the JSON object like this `i-object-metadata`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't use the object shorthand in this case, you'll have to use the array notation:

```
console.log(obj['i-object-metadata'].val); // 244
```

Comment: Thanks, Marc, it works well, I didn't know this approach before